# SQL Server cursor - loop through multiple servers and execute query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I have the following code (cursor):

```
DECLARE @SN VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT DISTINCT(SERVERNAME) FROM INSTALLATION 
    where DATABASETYPE = 'MsSql' AND SERVERNAME IN ('x');

OPEN C;

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SN;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN 
    PRINT @SN;
    -- you could loop here for each database, if you'd define what that is
   SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb');
    SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM TABLE ';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SN;
END 
CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```

I would like to be able to loop through every server and execute a select statement on some (not all) of their databases.

The query is something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM TABLE
```

The server from where I am running the cursor has all the others as linked servers.

Comment: Its possible the only trick is to use complete names for each server. And make sure they are linked as you say.   So 'servername.dbo.databasename.table' would be an idea of what I am talking about. So you are in the right track.

Comment: have a look here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1767/execute-sql-server-query-on-multiple-servers-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Can you define "some (not all) of their databases"?

Comment: @Muhammed Ali: I cannot use Central Management Server, my servers are not in a domain, they are all standalone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SN VARCHAR(20);

DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT DISTINCT(SERVERNAME) FROM TABLE 
  where SERVERNAME NOT IN ('SRV1','SRV2','SRV3');

OPEN C;

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SN;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN 
    PRINT @SN;
    -- you could loop here for each database, if you'd define what that is
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @SN + '.master.dbo.TABLE;';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SN;
END 
CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```

Changes:

1. There is no reason to use the default cursor options here - global, updatable, dynamic, scrollable, etc. [Background](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options).
2. As a habit / best practice, use `sp_executesql` and not `EXEC()`. While it doesn't really matter in this case, it can matter in others, so I'd prefer to always code the same way. [Background](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).
3. Also, please get in the habit of terminating your statements with semi-colons. You'll have to, eventually. [Background](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

**EDIT**

Now that we have a little more information about your actual requirements, I suggest this bit of code. Oh, and look, no cursors (well, no *explicit* cursor declarations and all the scaffolding that comes with them)!

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @dbs TABLE(SERVERNAME SYSNAME, DBNAME SYSNAME);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

-- first, let's get the databases on each server:

SELECT @sql += N'SELECT ''' + SERVERNAME + ''', name FROM '
 + QUOTENAME(SERVERNAME) + '.master.sys.databases
   WHERE database_id > 4 
   AND name NOT IN (N''somedb'',N''someotherdb'');' 
 FROM dbo.INSTALLATION 
   WHERE DATABASETYPE = 'MsSql' 
   AND SERVERNAME IN ('x');

INSERT @dbs EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT @sql = N'';

-- now, build a command to run in each database context:

SELECT @sql += N'
  EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(SERVERNAME) + '.'
  + QUOTENAME(DBNAME) + '.sys.sp_executesql @sql;'
  FROM @dbs;

-- feel free to change the 3rd parameter here:

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)', 
  N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), actual_columns FROM dbo.table_name;';
```

This will fail if table_name doesn't exist, so you may still have some work to do if you want to facilitate error handling. But this should get you started.

Also, please be conscious of, and consistently use, the schema prefix. [Background](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: I know ; matters with CTE but is there any other place other than CTE where it is mandatory in sql server ? Sorry just read your article read about the merge statement. but is there any other place where it matters ??

Comment: @Muhammed There are more and more places with each release. But stop worrying about where it's required today. Just use it everywhere; then, when it is required everywhere, you'll have less code to update.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions regarding the code, I have updated the top question. Unfortunately I still lack something to make it functional. I'm getting 

(27 row(s) affected)
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: You need to define @sql as NVARCHAR(MAX), not VARCHAR(100 ). There are still issues with your code though. Do you want to execute on all non-system databases on each server? What do you want to happen when the table doesn't exist? Remember there are other databases that are not in your list such as reporting services, SSIS catalog, and of course 3rd party products...

Comment: Theoretically yes it should run on all non-system databases because I don't have anything else except user databases. The table should also exist in all of them, if it doesn't I guess it will throw an error about it? Problem is if I set SET @sql = N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME '; it prints me the local server, when it should give me the remote server name. What am I missing?

Comment: @anarchist `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` will run locally if you just say `EXEC` or `EXEC sp_executesql`. How will it know to run at some other server?

Comment: well this is my problem, I don't know how to write it to be executed remotely

Comment: @anarchist I know that, which is why I updated the code once I understood your problem better. My previous comment was just explaining why it was executing locally - there is nothing in that command that tells it to go to another server.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you edited your post. Code looks great, it's a little complex for me, I modify EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)', 
  N'SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM SETTINGS UNION select URL from CLIENTURL;'; and it does return good values, however I don't know why it says Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'SETTINGS'. in messages, this table does exist

Comment: Oh there seems to be another db on some servers that does not contain the table, but your syntax is too complex for me, can you tell me how to exclude it? I tried something like: and WHERE name not IN 'OTHERDB'

Comment: @anarchist I've added a where clause to the remote query that will allow you to filter out databases matching a specific name.

Comment: It works great! Many thanks, your code is awesome. Just one more question: I can put anything inside N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), actual_columns FROM dbo.table_name;'; and it will be executed on the remote servers right? I'm thinking to use this to propagate a stored procedure on all servers.

Comment: @anarchist you *could*, but troubleshooting such a script is not how I'd want to spend my days. [There are tools that do this for you](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/)...